# How to delay the rendering of the page until vue variables are flushed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use [`vue.js`](https://vuejs.org/) to display some bound variables. The skeleton of my page is

```
<body>
<!-- the content of the page, including an instance of the variable {{hello}} -->
<script src="vue.js"></script>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
```

When opening the page, there is a brief moment where the page displays `{{hello}}`, which immediately after is replaced with the correct value of the variable `hello`.

What is the correct way (if any), to delay the displaying of the page until the variable is initialized and displays its value?

I believe it is due to [Vue's asynchronous nature](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue) (the queue is not flushed yet when the first rendering happens) but I do know how to hide this not-flushed yet stage on page opening.

Comment: where is the vue instance is being mounted on?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal: it is being mounted on a container `div`, encompassing all my page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [v-cloak](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak) for this, Following is how this is used:

> This directive will remain on the element until the associated Vue instance finishes compilation. Combined with CSS rules such as [v-cloak] { display: none }, this directive can be used to hide un-compiled mustache bindings until the Vue instance is ready.

**Example:**
CSS:

```
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div v-cloak>
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

This is very similar to [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak), if you know Angular.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I put it in the "container" `div` (the one I use as `el` when defining my Vue instance) and it indeed hides the mustache version. (+1, now waiting for the cool-down to accept the answer)

Comment: Didn't know this existed :/ but the {{ moustache }} never happened to me.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal You may have put v-if checks to prevent these?

Comment: @Saurabh Highly likely. Also I think because I use the scaffolding from `vue-cli` and leave the `app.js` to contain the `<router-view>` also had some role to play.